# How to display decimal value in PHP FPDF?

Tags: php, decimal, fpdf

This is my code :

```
$no=1;
while($item = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    $pdf->Cell(10   ,5,$no++,1,0);
    $pdf->Cell(100  ,5,$item['naran'],1,0);
    //add thousand separator using number_format function
    $pdf->Cell(25   ,5,number_format ( $item['folin_faan']),1,0);
    $pdf->Cell(25   ,5,number_format( $item['hamutuk']),1,0);
    $pdf->Cell(34   ,5,number_format( $item['total']),1,1,'R');//end of line
    //accumulate tax and amount
    $tax += $item['hamutuk'];
    $total += $item['total'];

}
```

It is supposed to display decimal value like `0.00`

The column I want display decimal value:

[image]

Question : how exactly function to display decimal value?

Comment: If I answered your question it would be nice if you would mark it accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Your [number_format()](http://php.net/number_format) parameters seem off if you desire `0.00` and similar.

Try this:

```
number_format($item['total'], 2, '.', '');
```

This shows `2` decimals using `.` as decimal point and having  (nothing) as thousands separator.

---

Full code:

```
$no=1;
while($item = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    $pdf->Cell(10, 5, $no++, 1, 0);
    $pdf->Cell(100, 5, $item['naran'], 1, 0);
    // add thousand separator using number_format function
    $pdf->Cell(25, 5, number_format($item['folin_faan'], 2, '.', ''), 1, 0);
    $pdf->Cell(25, 5, number_format($item['hamutuk'], 2, '.', ''), 1, 0);
    $pdf->Cell(34, 5, number_format($item['total'], 2, '.', ''), 1, 1, 'R'); // end of line
    // accumulate tax and amount
    $tax += $item['hamutuk'];
    $total += $item['total'];
}
```

Comment: and how to add on here as well : $total += ($item['total']; i want to display as variable ---> $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',12);
$pdf->Cell(189 ,10,'',0,1);//end of line
$pdf->Cell(20 ,5,'TOTAL :$',0,0);
$pdf->Cell(130 ,5,$total,0,1);
$pdf->Cell(180 ,4,'',0,1);//end of line
$pdf->Cell(12 ,5,'Date :',0,0);
$pdf->Cell(59 ,5,$currentdate,0,1);

Comment: I'm sorry but I have no idea what exactly you're asking of.

Comment: $pdf->Cell(130,5,$total,0,1); this is the  place to display value of $total += $item['total']; how to add on here as well?

Comment: `$pdf->Cell(130 ,5, number_format($total, 2, '.', ''), 0, 1);` ? I really suggest you read the page I linked to. Wherever you want a formatted number with decimals, just place the `number_format()` function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
$this->Cell(30,20,"C$ ".number_format($data->precio_venta,2,'.',','),1,0,'L');
```

The result will be `C$ 2,500.00` if it takes thousands, `C$ 450.00` if it takes hundreds.

Comment: Todas las respuestas deben estar en inglés. ¿Podrías traducir y también echar un vistazo a las pautas sobre cómo formatear tu publicación? [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help).